# Conditional formatting applied to only one cell of range

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

In Excel 2010 a conditional formatting rule based on the values in three adjoining cells in a row is applied to only the first cell of the three rather than to all three cells. The rule was created when all three cells were selected.

First, the screenshot:

[image: Set of worksheet cells]

The formula is `=AND(C12>$E$2,C12<$E$3,D12>$E$4,D12<$E$5,E12>$E$6,E12<$E$7)`

Under Conditional formatting, Manage rules, Applies to is `=$C$12:$E$12`

If it matters: the Min & Max values are determined by formulas. The Altitude, Azimuth & Reflection values are keyed in.

The question is: how can the conditional formatting be applied to all three cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `$` in front of all the column letters other wise they will refer to the wrong columns as Conditional Formatting moves across the row:

```
=AND($C12>$E$2,$C12<$E$3,$D12>$E$4,$D12<$E$5,$E12>$E$6,$E12<$E$7)
```

Then you can change the `Applies to:` to `=$C$12:$E$20` to capture all the rows.